# How to print multi line text box value without '\n' by tkinter

Tags: mysql, tkinter

I want to print textbox value without '\n' from tkinter,
When I print then it show one line and next line valu adding with "\n', actually I fetch the valu from mysql

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] with sample data.  I do not have such issue with text having newlines saved in my MySQL table.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a `\n` from the end of a string, use `rstrip('\n')`:

```py
lines = [
    "Hello, world!\n",
    "No newline",
    "", # empty
    "Two\nNewlines\n",
    "Intermediate\nNewline",
]

for line in lines:
    s = line.rstrip("\n")
    print("-" * 20)
    print(s)

# gives
"""
--------------------
Hello, world!
--------------------
No newline
--------------------

--------------------
Two
Newlines
--------------------
Intermediate
Newline
"""
```

Comment: Relatedly - if you type `help(str)` into an interactive window you'll find all kinds of useful stuff, even if you've been using Python for a while.