# How to insert multi line MySQL data in tkinter textbox?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

How to insert multi line `MySQL` data in tkinter textbox?
I need data in textbox like

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

But I got data in textbox like

```
Line1\nline2\nLine3
```

When I fetching the data from mysql

Comment: How are you showing the data? `\n` is the representation of a newline in a string literal.

Comment: maybe databases keep it as `\\n` and later Python displays it as `\n`. We can't see code, we can't see data from database, and we can't read in your mind - you have to add all details in question (not in comments)

Comment: You have already asked similar questions: [How to print multi line text box value without '\n' by tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71034444/how-to-print-multi-line-text-box-value-without-n-by-tkinter) and [MySQL multi line data fetch in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70995677/mysql-multi-line-data-fetch-in-tkinter).